# Background não funciona

Tags: html, css, css3, background

Estou tentando aplicar o CSS abaixo em uma div para usar um background, mas ele não aparece de maneira alguma.

HTML

```
<div class="row background-1">
    <div class="col col-2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eu efficitur magna, eu sodales lorem. Proin sem lectus, congue nec scelerisque rhoncus, commodo vel orci. Nunc sed ligula hendrerit, pharetra augue quis, auctor lorem. Vestibulum quis varius libero, ac commodo velit. Mauris sodales lobortis euismod.
    </div>
    <div class="col col-4">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eu efficitur magna, eu sodales lorem. Proin sem lectus, congue nec scelerisque rhoncus, commodo vel orci. Nunc sed ligula hendrerit, pharetra augue quis, auctor lorem. Vestibulum quis varius libero, ac commodo velit. Mauris sodales lobortis euismod.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS do background

```
div.background-1 {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/FyMaZlK.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

CSS que estou utilizando para as colunas

```
.col {
    border:0px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    float:left;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-background-clip:padding-box !important;
    -webkit-background-clip:padding-box !important;
    background-clip:padding-box !important;
}
    @media screen and (min-width: 0px) {

        .col {
            margin-left:2%;
            padding:0 1.5%;
        }

        .row .col:first-child {
            margin-left:0;
        }
        .col-1 {
            width:15.0%;
        }
        .col-2 {
            width:32.0%;
        }
        .col-3 {
            width:49.0%;
        }
        .col-4 {
            width:66.0%;
        }
        .col-5 {
            width:83.0%;
        }
        .col-6 {
            margin-left:0;
            width:100%;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que esta acontecendo é que o background esta funcionando, porém a sua div não esta acompanhando o conteudo dentro dela, então, no css adicione:

```
display: table;
```

```css
.background-1 {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/FyMaZlK.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
 display:table;
}
.col {
    border:0px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    float:left;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-background-clip:padding-box !important;
    -webkit-background-clip:padding-box !important;
    background-clip:padding-box !important;
}
    @media screen and (min-width: 0px) {

        .col {
            margin-left:2%;
            padding:0 1.5%;
        }

        .row .col:first-child {
            margin-left:0;
        }
        .col-1 {
            width:15.0%;
        }
        .col-2 {
            width:32.0%;
        }
        .col-3 {
            width:49.0%;
        }
        .col-4 {
            width:66.0%;
        }
        .col-5 {
            width:83.0%;
        }
        .col-6 {
            margin-left:0;
            width:100%;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="row background-1">
    <div class="col col-2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eu efficitur magna, eu sodales lorem. Proin sem lectus, congue nec scelerisque rhoncus, commodo vel orci. Nunc sed ligula hendrerit, pharetra augue quis, auctor lorem. Vestibulum quis varius libero, ac commodo velit. Mauris sodales lobortis euismod.
    </div>
    <div class="col col-4">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eu efficitur magna, eu sodales lorem. Proin sem lectus, congue nec scelerisque rhoncus, commodo vel orci. Nunc sed ligula hendrerit, pharetra augue quis, auctor lorem. Vestibulum quis varius libero, ac commodo velit. Mauris sodales lobortis euismod.
    </div>
  
</div>
```

Espero ter ajudado!!!

Answer (score 0):

O *background* está sendo aplicado corretamente o problema é que se você inspecionar o elemento em que está o *background*, você verá que seu tamanho é de `0x0`. Isso acontece porque todos os elementos dentro dele possuem um `float: left`, o que de certa forma, desabilita o `width: auto` e `height: auto` padrão do elemento `div`.

Você pode contornar isso de duas formas: ou você aplica um `display: inline-block` na `div.background-1`, ou você a defini com um *width* específico, por exemplo, `100%`.

#### Veja

```css
div.background-1 {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/FyMaZlK.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.col {
  display: block;
  border: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  clear: right;
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding-box !important;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box !important;
  background-clip: padding-box !important;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0px) {
  .col {
    margin-left: 2%;
    padding: 0 1.5%;
  }
  .row .col:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .col-1 {
    width: 15.0%;
  }
  .col-2 {
    width: 32.0%;
  }
  .col-3 {
    width: 49.0%;
  }
  .col-4 {
    width: 66.0%;
  }
  .col-5 {
    width: 83.0%;
  }
  .col-6 {
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row background-1">
  <div class="col col-2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eu efficitur magna, eu sodales lorem. Proin sem lectus, congue nec scelerisque rhoncus, commodo vel orci. Nunc sed ligula hendrerit, pharetra augue quis, auctor lorem. Vestibulum quis varius
    libero, ac commodo velit. Mauris sodales lobortis euismod.
  </div>
  <div class="col col-4">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eu efficitur magna, eu sodales lorem. Proin sem lectus, congue nec scelerisque rhoncus, commodo vel orci. Nunc sed ligula hendrerit, pharetra augue quis, auctor lorem. Vestibulum quis varius
    libero, ac commodo velit. Mauris sodales lobortis euismod.
  </div>
</div>
```